# is there any overriding that does not fall under dynamic polymorphism

Tags: java, polymorphism, overriding

Recently in an interview I was asked, "What is an example of dynamic polymorphism in Java?"

I answered, "Method overriding".

The interviewer then asked, "Is there any overriding concept that does not come into dynamic polymorphism?"

Is this really a good question?  If yes, what is the answer?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Dynamic polymorphism? That's redundant. There's no static polymorphism. Read up on late-binding.

Comment: May be he/she referring to shadowing?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Static polymorphism is overloading, dynamic polymorphism is overriding, far as I understand it.

Comment: @Marconius Not at all. Overloading has nothing to do with polymorphism. Polymorphism _allows values of different data types to be handled using a uniform interface_ [(wiki)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science)).

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Polymorphism concerns methods as well; all my searches turn up results that basically say static polymorphism is any kind of new definition evaluated at compile time, dynamic is evaluated at runtime. [Source](http://www.erpgreat.com/java/static-and-dynamic-polymorphism.htm) [Another source](http://www.geekinterview.com/question_details/57993)

Comment: @Marconius Both those sources are using the term `polymorphism` incorrectly, for early/static binding. In late binding (to enable polymorphism), methods are chosen (in a uniform manner) based on the data type of the object you're accessing. In static binding, methods are chosen based on their method signature and for the same data type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the question was on C++, then the answer would have been "yes" since member functions do not have to be virtual. In Java, however, all methods are *virtual functions* in C++ terms, therefore it is impossible to involve the concept of overriding without involving dynamic dispatch, which results in polymorphic behavior.

Any other example of naming a member the same as a member of a superclass, is not called *overriding*, but *hiding*, and is a completely different concept: the subclass member is in no way related to the superclass member, it just happens to have the same name. The subclass may even *inherit* the same-named member and thus have two same-named members, which can still both be accessed by qualifying the member name with the class name.

Comment: I have also heard "hiding" called "shadowing", for reference.

Comment: @CoryKendall There is also "obscuring" and they are all distinct concepts, precisely defined by the [Java Language Specification, §6.4.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.4.1).